# Sync session timeout with Azure Active Directory using OpenID provider

Tags: asp.net, azure, session

I am working ASP.Net MVC 5.0 application and deployed into Azure environment. For authentication, I'm using Azure Active Directory with OpenID connect provider.

I am storing some user related data in session. After 20 minutes, session will expire, and session data will get cleared, but authentication doesn't expired automatically.

Is there any option available in OpenID to invalidate the authentication, and redirect to login page automatically?

Comment: You mean like an HTTP call you could make that would invalidate a particular user's session? No I do not think so. But you can always log them out with a redirect.

Comment: No, After 20 minutes session got expired, when user redirect to any page its not redirect to login page, considered the current user is logged-in, and application not behaving properly because session data is empty. I want to redirect OpenId/AD login page after session expired.