# Redirect to login after session expired

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect

Am using Azure Active directory with OpenId provider in MVC 5.0 application and deployed into the Azure portal, In my case user session get expired after 20 minutes but not automatically redirecting to login page, application considered authentication is valid.

Is there any option available in OpenId provider to signout and redirect to login page again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sync session timeout with Azure Active Directory using OpenID provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48583447/sync-session-timeout-with-azure-active-directory-using-openid-provider)